# Image not appearing in .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map that displays data from an array in another jsx file.

```
{data.map((nftDetail) => {
        return (
          <div className="card" key={nftDetail.id}>
            <img src={nftDetail.img} alt="" />
            <h3>{nftDetail.title}</h3>
            <h4>{nftDetail.owner}</h4>
            <h5>{nftDetail.category}</h5>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

Data example :
{
id: 1,
title: "#247",
category: "Top",
owner:"c568c3",
img:"../../assets/1.png"
},

The image is not appearing (everything else is displayed)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdDo4.png)

Do i need to import something else? Why is the photo not appearing? Thanks!

Comment: Open your browser console and look at the network requests to debug. Sounds like your paths aren't right.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i moved the photo to the same folder as this file just in case my paths weren't right

Comment: Like I said, open your browser console to see the path and the server response, and check that the file actually exists on the server there (sounds like it doesn't)

Comment: https://ibb.co/k55ZZw0 https://ibb.co/5kK85rc The img appears but it's blank

Answer (score -1):

./1.png - does this path contain the image can you check that and use a correct path reference for the image

Comment: I moved the photo to the same folder as this js file not to make a path error but i corrected it to the original path in the folder assets

Comment: When i go to network i see the image but it's blank.  ibb.co/k55ZZw0 ibb.co/5kK85rc